# How to get my button to trigger an element

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs to compile my code and antd framework. I am unable to style the positioning of my button, also I want my `start` button to trigger a set of buttons but for some reason it does not work. Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import { Radio } from "antd";

export default class PositiveAffirmation extends Component {
  state = {
    changeButton: false
  };

  toggleChangeButton = e => {
    this.setState({
      changeButton: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { changeButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Radio.Group
          defaultValue="false"
          buttonStyle="solid"
          onChange={this.changeButton}
          className="radio-buttons"
        >
          <Radio.Button value={true}>Start</Radio.Button>
          <Radio.Button value={false}>Stop</Radio.Button>
        </Radio.Group>
        {changeButton && (
          <Button.Group size={size}>
            <Button type="primary">Happy</Button>
            <Button type="primary">Sad</Button>
            <Button type="primary">Fullfiled</Button>
          </Button.Group>
        )}
        <style jsx>{`
          Radio.Button {
            font-size: 100px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
          }
        `}</style>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be a lot easier for someone to help you if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: Instead of using booleans  (true and false) try using strings i.e "true" "false" or "start" "stop" in your state use the default "false" or "stop" maybe and in the render use changeButton === "true" or "start" whichever you choose instead.

Comment: Here is my snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/n4rwrwyjlm. I need help on how to implement the styling. I am using next.js to build my app.

Comment: Tholle do you think you could have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849855/how-do-i-handle-my-reactions-with-my-redux-reducers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling just wrong fn change `onChange={this.changeButton}`  to `onChange={this.toggleChangeButton}`

Comment: Ohhhh, how did I miss that? Thanks.

Again I can't seem to style my buttons, I am new to nextJs, any help with that? https://codesandbox.io/s/n4rwrwyjlm

Comment: - I seen that you are using `antd`. `antd` has its css file which we have to import in our root component for use default styles. 
- For implementing css in next js you'll need @zeit/next-css and need to change in `next.config.js` file.

here is the code with changes https://codesandbox.io/s/5p3vxow7p