# How do I handle my reactions with my redux reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have three icons with a text that should increment on each if clicked, that handles my reactions on a post. The idea is that I can have one reaction clicked at a time and that double clicking a reaction reverses to the previous state the conventional way a reaction on posts work. I have mapped out steps to take, I have created my actions and done the basics for the reducers but at this point I do not know how to proceed.

These are the steps:

1. In redux store, save the data for each card inside of a map, default state of all initial data is in a Map.
2. Populate the view with items from the Map
3. On reaction update, trigger action that takes an item `Id` and a `reaction` key (which is an object) with a type and value
4. Reducer consumes data from action and find item by Id

5.Update the given reaction type of the item

`reducers.js`

```
import { DISLIKE_REACTION, LIKE_REACTION, MAYBE_REACTION } from './actionTypes';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  reactionFlow: new Map(),
};

/**
* Creates a Javascript Map for each card as an object mapped by id
*
* @param {Array} reactions - array of user reaction objects
* @return {Map} - the new reaction list
*/
function generateItemMap(reactions) {
const setOfReactions = new Map();

reactions.forEach(reaction => {
    const { _id } = reaction;

    setOfReactions.set(_id, reaction);
});

return setOfReactions;
}

/**
* Updates the given reaction type of the item
*
* @param {Object} reaction - the reaction object with a type and value
* @param {Map} type - the type of reactions
* @return {Map} - the updated user reaction
*/
function updateReactionType(reaction, type) {
const { _id } = reaction;
const newType = new Map([...type.entries()]);

newType.set(_id, reaction);

return newType;
}

export default (state = { ...INITIAL_STATE }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case LIKE_REACTION: {
        return {
            ...state,
        };
    }

    case DISLIKE_REACTION: {
        return {
        };
    }

    case MAYBE_REACTION: {
        return {
            ...state,
        };
    }

    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

actions.js

```
/**
 * Triggers request to like or unlike post
 *
 * @function
 * @return {Object} The {@link actionTypes.LIKE_REACTION LIKE_REACTION}
 * action.
 */
export const likeReaction = () => ({
    type: LIKE_REACTION,
});

/**
 * Triggers request to dislike post or reverse dislike
 *
 * @function
 *
 * @param {Object} payload - the data sent with the action
 * @return {Object} The {@link actionTypes.DISLIKE_REACTION DISLIKE_REACTION}
 * action.
 */
export const dislikeReaction = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: DISLIKE_REACTION,
});

/**
 * Triggers request to maybe post or reverse maybe
 *
 * @function
 *
 * @param {Object} payload - the data sent with the action
 * @return {Object} The {@link actionTypes.MAYBE_REACTION MAYBE_REACTION}
 * action.
 */
export const maybeReaction = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: MAYBE_REACTION,
});
```

component

```
  <span>
    <Icon type={type} />
    {text}
  </span>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should return the modified state for your application.

```
   export default (state = { ...INITIAL_STATE }, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
      case LIKE_REACTION: 
        const { Id, reaction } = action.payload;
        let newState = { ...state }; //be careful, this is a shallow copy
        //TODO: perform the changes you want in state here
        //newState = something...
        return newState;
```

Comment: Let's say I had something like this case


`LIKE_REACTION: {


        const { payload } = action;


        const { reactionFlow } = state;


        return {


            ...state,


            reactionFlow: updateReactionType(payload, reactionFlow),


        };


 }`


How do I proceed from here and the next cases to my component.

Comment: Your component uses *connect* from redux and it receives this state as props as you stated in *mapStateToProps*? If so, react/redux will take care of updating that component. If not, you can follow the [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react). I am not sure if I understand what you mean by next cases. If you mean cases in the switch/case, each case should provide the necessary changes to the redux store according to its action intention. If you mean other components interactions, each interaction is independent and will trigger one update to the redux store/component

Answer (score 0):

Assign your value which you want to update at reducer in switch case like this:

```
case LIKE_REACTION: {
        return {
            ...state,
            value: action.payload
        };
    }
```

You get you update value at you component over here:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return{
       value: state.value
    }
};
```

Now you get your update value at:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, preProps) {
        this.setState({value: nextProps.value})
    }
```

Now you use your updated state value in component as a this.state.value.

For more understanding of react life cycle read: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: I am more confused. Is it possible you could give a specific working example?

Answer (score 0):

check this example i created - https://codesandbox.io/s/yp18326mzx

So basically we have 2 actions to increment and decrement which manipulates the data in a central store, is this what you need ?

Comment: No, not at all? It's like this; I have three reactions: `like` , `dislike` and `maybe`. I click on `like`, it increments by 1, I click again it decreases by 1 and vice versa just like in any conventional site you've come across, like facebook, twitter or whatever. Also I cannot have `like` and `dislike` clicked at the same time, it is either of them.

Comment: One way to do it is to maintain the state like - liked:null , if liked is "True" toggle the like icon to ON , if liked is "False" toggle the dislike icon to ON , if "Null" disable both like Dislike , you can maintain another state for maybe

Comment: If you are using for comments like on facebook - your state would be something like State = {"Comment":"something", liked:True, Maybe:False}